# Differentiate receiving file on socket

Tags: c, sockets, file-upload, file-io, flags

I have a question regarding sockets. I use a socket to transfer data from A to B, process the file at B and then send an response from B to A. Now I would like to (ab)use the same socket to send a different file. That file should not be processed (just saved). The question is how can I differentiate those two files?

Is there a way to parse the actual file name or can I use a flag or something?

An idea was that my send method uses fread to read the whole file and I guess when I copy a complete file, the file name is included. But since I have to open a new file with fopen at the receiving file, I have to give a new file name.

Comment: `The question is how can I differentiate those two files?` - Use file name to differentiate it! send the file name along with file content and do the operation based on your file name and content received!

Comment: You mean I add the file name to the file?

Comment: ya! In that way it is possible! but look for some other ideas also, because someone may have better idea!

Comment: "*I guess when I copy a complete file, the file name is included.*" in general this is not the case. (if not for any reason you explcitly wrote the file's name into the file itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define a simple protocol to describe what you're sending over the socket.

1. byte indicating the length of the filename
2. array of chars representing the filename
3. byte indicating whether the file should be processed
4. uint32 indicating the size of the file
5. array of bytes making up the file contents

You can obviously adapt this to suit your needs, but defining something clearly like this makes the transfer more robust and makes it very simple to determine whether to process the file or not.

Comment: I'd give **two** bytes for the length of the file name. There are also other systems then windows ... ;-) However 1+ for proposing to define and implement a "protocol"!

Comment: I like your protocol. I combined it with Arpits third option by sending an int as a flag before transferring the file. As soon as I know that I have to process the file, I don't need the file name. I will mark it as an answer because it's a good general approach!

Answer (score 0):

First, when you read the contents of a file, the filename is not included in the data until and unless you are not explicitly writing the filename into the data.

Second, if you know by filename, at B side, whether it is suppose to process or not then you can add the filename in the starting of the data and putting a special identifiers to indicate the start of the data. This way you will get the filename if it is suppose to be saved.

Third, other than the putting the filename in the data, you can add a bit like a flag indicating whether to process the file or not. And then you can read the rest of the data.

Comment: I used your third option by just sending a flag (int) before I send the data. Sending a file name creates a overhead and is not necessary as long as I can distinguish between both files.